# Is it possible to gether the exchange rates from bitpanda?

Tags: jquery, cloudflare

I'd like to gather the exchanges rates from BitPanda https://www.bitpanda.com/trades/buy. Especially, the value of the base-price section.

I have already some code which is able to call the website. But then I can’t proceed further because of some spam-protection software (cloudflare). On the other hand, I can’t extract the value next to the base-price label.

Some advises, how to solve these problems? Thanks in advance!

Code to call the site with jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON('http://allorigins.me/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent('https://www.bitpanda.com//trades/buy') + '&callback=?', function(data){
      var el  = document.createElement("html");
      el.innerHTML = data.contents.substr(16);
      console.log(el);
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: we have a ticker now fyi ;) https://www.bitpanda.com/api/ticker

Comment: You are **awesome**, man! 
This will make the work much easier. Just a short question. Is it possible to get the information of  a specific currency [for example €]? What would be very nice =)

Comment: no problem man, we currently only support EUR, so you have to do the conversion to other currencies by yourself sry

Comment: Url changed to https://api.bitpanda.com/v1/ticker in case you still need this, now also with multiple fiat rates